# LibGDX Drawing text to top-left corner

Tags: java, android, libgdx, game-engine, game-development

I'm new to libgdx and followed a tutorial to make a simple game, now i wanted to extend a small part myself that is adding an fps counter in the top left corner of the screen

The code i used is copy-pasted from https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-Simple-Game (scroll to end for the final code)

In render method just after clearing the screen and updating the camera i did something like this

```
font.draw(batch, String.valueOf(Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond()), 0, 480);
```

(I added a font field initialized with new BitmapFont(); and obviously i wrapped the text drawing in a batch.begin() and end)

The game crashes on start, but i don't get it

From my mind it works this way

x is 0 because i want the start of the left corner

480 y to draw at the top, the camera is of height 480 so that is top-left corner this way.

Now the question is am i misunderstanding the coordinate system or if not then what's exactly wrong in my code? I'm testing on Android btw.

Comment: Could you please post the details of your crash here?

Comment: BTW, I have no idea about LibGDX, but in most drawing libraries `(0, 0)` already represents the top, left corner. When this is the case, adding to the Y dimension means moving down.

Comment: If that was the case then it would've drawn it on the bottom atleast, and I've read a couple of resources that libgdx's drawing is (0, 0) bottom left, it can be changed with camera.setOrtho(true) but I'm clearly passing false, for sending details unfortunately i can't as I don't have access to a computer rn and built the apk on Android itself so i don't have logcat or any sort of console to check.

Comment: LibGdx (0, 0) is in the bottom left corner by default. I don't think the crash comes because you draw your font on this position. I think the problem is in another place. Maybe you call a second-time `batch.begin()` before `batch.end()` or your font is not correctly loaded. I can't be sure as long as I can't see a crash report or some more code.

Comment: crash log please ?

Comment: @Morchul yup u were right, the font wasn't being bundled properly i copied it out to my own assets folder and loaded it from there and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, the font wasn't being bundled properly, i extracted the font files from the gdx jar file and placed it to my own assets folder and it works now.